# KVPY Question: Sequence and Series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> $S_n = \cfrac{7}{4 \cdot 1 \cdot 2} + \cfrac{10}{4^2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3} + \cfrac{13}{4^3 \cdot 3 \cdot 4} + ....$, then $S_{\infty}=$

I found the general term:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{n \rightarrow \infty} \cfrac{(3n+4)}{n(n+1)4^{n}} = $$

How to evaluate further? Please help.

---

*I am at an elementary level, so this question might seem dumb, sorry.*

Comment: Do you know about partial fractions? If so, then you can obtain (in a direct way, not simply by verifying what I give) $\frac{(3n+4)}{n(n+1)} = \frac{4}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1},$ which will be helpful (note that $\frac{4}{4^n} = \frac{1}{4^{n-1}}).$

Comment: Use a partial fraction expansion $(3n+4)/(n(n+1)) = 4/n - 1/(n+1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{4n+3}{(n+1)4^n}=\frac 1{4^{n-1}\cdot n}-\frac 1{4^n\cdot (n+1)}$$

Now we give values $n=1 \rightarrow n$ and sum up and cancel similar terms :

$$\frac 1{4^0\cdot 1}-\frac 1{4\cdot 2}$$

$$\frac 1{4\cdot 2}-\frac 1{4^2\cdot 3}$$

$$\frac 1{4^2\cdot 3}-\frac 1{4^3\cdot 4}$$

$$\frac 1{4^3\cdot 4}-\frac 1{4^4\cdot 5}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$\frac 1{4^{n-2}\cdot(n-1) }-\frac 1{4^{n-1}\cdot n}$$

$$\frac 1{4^{n-1}\cdot n}-\frac 1{4^n\cdot (n+1)}$$

$$\therefore S_n=1-\frac 1{4^n(n+1)}$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} S_n=1$$